# Wow.js on elements with background images on Safari display incorrectly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image, wow.js

I am using [Wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html) on my site and it works fine on all browsers (even IE...) except Safari (running on windows). I am using Bootstrap 3.

I see the following error in the console:

```
MutationObserver is not supported by your browser.
wow.min.js:2WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call .sync() after loading new content.
```

There is some mention of this issue [here](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/166) but it is in the context of loading content via AJAX which I am not doing.

Here's my markup:

```
<style>
    section#background-img{
        background: url("img.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
</style>


<section id="background-img">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="800ms">
                <h2>What I can do for you</h2>
                <h3>And how I can help your business grow</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="800ms">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <!-- content removed for brevity-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It should look like this:
[image]

But instead I see this:
[image]

I use Wow.js elsewhere on this page which works fine. The problem seems to arise when I use background images.